# Display items in different styles(List, Grid, Blocks) in Xamarin ios?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i am new to xamarin ios.
i want to implement display items in different styles (List,Grid,Blocks) in view controller.
I tried with table view cell, But i am unable to make it proper.
Please find the below images.
When ever we click on icons (List icon, grid icon, Block icon) we need to display the different styles view in same view controller.
Please suggest me how to make it possible.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you are talking about view controllers and table view cells I assume you are not working with Xamarin Forms.
This means you are creating a native iOS user interface and what you are trying to accomplish can be done with a `UICollectionView`.
In particular you want to use the `performBatchUpdates:completion:` method, which allows you to animate reload and move operations.

- Xamarin example: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/CircleLayout
- Very good and comprehensive tutorial (Objective-C): https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/collectionview-animations/
- There are two videos about collection views from the WWDC 12 which I suggest you too see: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2012/
- Introduction to collection view tutorial (Swift): https://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1
- Tutorial on animations while dragging collection view elements (Swift): http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/

Comment: Hi @DAN, thank you so much for your quick response. if you provide any  example, it will help me a lot.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your reply. i am working on it. If possible can you send the similar(items display design) code with test data.