# iOS collectionView from grid to list with 2 prototypes cells

Tags: ios, list, grid, cells, collectionview

I want to make a collection with 2 styles : Grid and List.

So, at the moment, I have :

- 1 collection View
- 2 flow Layout
- 1 dataSource
- 2 prototypes cells

I have to use the same datasource. I can switch between layout, it's not a problem.

But my **GetCell** method in my **DataSource** returns a cell from only 1 prototype. So when I switch, disposition cells are change **but not their content.**

GetCellMethod :

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Transaction transaction = Transactions[indexPath.Row];

        var cell = (TransactionCellList)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("transactionList", indexPath);

        cell.UpdateRow(transaction);

        return cell;

    }
```

How can I make a difference between these 2 prototypes cells using a switch button grid / list ??

Thanks a lot for help !!!

PS : Image here on stack post : [Display items in different styles(List, Grid, Blocks) in Xamarin ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173117/display-items-in-different-styleslist-grid-blocks-in-xamarin-ios)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but I guess that you have some Bool value to know if you are using list or grid type, no? Then, if (isInList) {dequeueCellList}else{dequeueCellGrid}? (in pseudo code)

Comment: I got the impression that my GetCell is called only 1 time, so when I switch it doesn't call it again to dequeue other cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .isSelected property of UIButton to switch between the cells

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
Transaction transaction = Transactions[indexPath.Row];
if switch.isSelected {
 var cell = (TransactionCellList)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("transactionList", indexPath);

        cell.UpdateRow(transaction);

        return cell;

}
        else{
   var cell = (TransactionCellList)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("transactionGrid", indexPath);

        cell.UpdateRow(transaction);

        return cell;
}


 }
```

In `IBAction` of the switch button you can use 
s`witch.isSelected. = !switch.isSelected`

Comment: Thanks for answer but in my datasource class, I don't have any access to my button. So I can't use that , right ?

Comment: You can use a delegate to pass the value when the button is tapped.

Comment: Its ok, but I need to ReloadData() each time I switch ?

Comment: Yup you need to call ReloadData()

Comment: Ok thanks for answer ! It works but I got another problem :( ReloadData() change everytime I switch my cells content.. So I 1st transaction is well loaded 1st time, but each time I reload, It seems that 1st transaction is loaded with other transaction content.. and also some elements disappear... :(

Comment: Also, here I got 9 transactions, why the 1st time it loads 4 first transactions, and when I switch, it loads all 9 ?

Comment: The problem might be with the UpdateRow function and I believe the code that I have provided to switch cells doesn't have any impact on the error that you are getting

Comment: Ok I will search but don't understand why 1st time I switch, all transactions are well loaded, but when I switch again, no. Do I need to invalidate layout?

Comment: I'm sorry man I'm not sure but I try printing the Transactions array the second time you switch and see if its values are correct